# UIButton in subview called to method in Parent

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, subview

I'm using Universal links. 
so, when Universal link clicked the app is open and from the AppDelegate i'm loading ViewController:

```
ConViewController *con = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
 bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerName"];

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:con.view];
```

In this ("con") view controller I have UIView with a NIB:

```
UIView *NibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibName"
 owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

[_PageView addSubview:SingleView];



-------
| con |
|     |
|-----|
||Nib||
||   ||
|-----|
-------
```

The Problem:
In the NibView I have UIButton.
The implementation of the Button Action locate in "ConViewController".
But the the Action called only when I put the implementation in the AppDelegate (Parent).

Why its happen?
and how I can change it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding your ViewController on Window as a subView ,you are not setting your View Controller as a rootView Controller  or your are not pushing to your view controller( in detail you are adding only the view of your view controller on window) , your view controller are not in memory so  every action you create in your view controller not working as ,we have a stack based approach (i.e. stack of view controllers) and your viewController is not on stack or in memory , so if you create button action of appdelegate it works.

Comment: thank you for your response.
can you give me a reference  to learn more about it?